# On a property of curved polygons

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $A$ be an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and suppose $\partial A$ is a Jordan curve parametrized by a continuous function $\beta:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, in counter-clockwise direction.
Suppose moreover that $\partial A$ is piecewise the graph of a continuous function namely if
there are
$$
0=\hat b_0<\hat b_1<\dots<\hat b_{n-1}<\hat b_n=1\,,
$$
such that on each interval $[\hat b_{l-1},\hat b_l]$, $\beta$ restricted to $[\hat b_{l-1},\hat b_l]$ is the graph of a continuous function $f_l(x)$ and the interior of $A$ "stays below" the graph of $f_l$.

Suppose moreover that $\beta$ is a piecewise $\mathcal{C}^1$ with finite number of pieces and that there exists the limit from the right and from the left of the tangent vector at the endpoint of these pieces; namely the boundary is a "curved polygon". More precisely
there are
$$
0=\hat c_0<\hat c_1<\dots<\hat c_{k-1}<\hat c_k=1\,,
$$
such that on each interval $[\hat c_{l-1},\hat c_l]$, $\beta$ restricted to $[\hat c_{l-1},\hat c_l]$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ and there exist the limits.
$$
\lim_{t\to\hat c_l^+}\dot\beta(t)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\lim_{t\to\hat c_l^+}\dot\beta(t)
$$
for every $l$. (Clearly here the limit from the right in $1$ coincides with the limit from the left in $0$ by periodicity).
Under these hypotheses there exists a non auto intersecting (namely simple) polygonal curve having vertices
$$
c_0=\beta(t_0),\dots, c_k=\beta(t_k)
$$
on the curve $\beta$ with
$$
0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_{k-1}<t_k=1
$$
such that on each interval $[c_{j-1},c_j]$, $\beta$ restricted to $[c_{j-1},c_j]$ is the graph of a continuous function $g_j(x)$ and the interior of $A$ "stays below" the graph of $g_j$.

To summing up my question is the following:

Given a curved polygon that is piecewise the graph of a continuous function as given above there exist a simple polygon (with straight edges) with vertices on the curve such that each part (arc) of the curved polygon between two consecutive vertices of the simple straight edge polygon is the graph of a continuous function (as defined above)?

Any answer with a specific reference to books and/or articles will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your actual question?  Do you have a question about this construction or are you looking for resources that discuss it?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have edited the question to make clear my question.